# ASPxPivotGrid Loss data on post back

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I attach a data source to ASPxPivotGrid on page load it shows the data, it loses data when the filter, sort, or paging button is pressed.

```
private void LoadBankDetail1(string branch, DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo, string accounts)
 {

            ASPxPivotGrid1.DataSource = aglTransact.GetBankDetail(branch, dateFrom, dateTo, accounts, inputIncludOb.Checked);
}


<dx:ASPxPivotGrid ID="ASPxPivotGrid1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID"  EnableTheming="True" OnDataBinding="ASPxPivotGrid1_DataBinding" Theme="MaterialCompact">
    <Fields>
        <dx:PivotGridField ID="fieldaccountdesc" Area="RowArea" AreaIndex="1" Caption="Account" FieldName="account_desc" Name="fieldaccountdesc">
        </dx:PivotGridField>
        <dx:PivotGridField ID="fieldperiod" Area="ColumnArea" AreaIndex="0" Caption="Period" FieldName="period" Name="fieldperiod">
        </dx:PivotGridField>
        <dx:PivotGridField ID="fieldamount" Area="DataArea" AreaIndex="0" Caption="Amount" FieldName="amount" Name="fieldamount">
        </dx:PivotGridField>
        <dx:PivotGridField ID="fieldbranchdesc" Area="RowArea" AreaIndex="0" Caption="Branch" FieldName="branch_desc" Name="fieldbranchdesc">
        </dx:PivotGridField>
        <dx:PivotGridField ID="fieldbranchdesc1" AreaIndex="0" Caption="Branch" FieldName="branch_desc" Name="fieldbranchdesc1">
        </dx:PivotGridField>
    </Fields>
</dx:ASPxPivotGrid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you call the "LoadBankDetail1" procedure (where you assign ASPxPivotGrid1.DataSource) during EACH request, i.e., NOT under something like "if (!IsPostBack)" etc. on Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    LoadBankDetail1(...);
}
```